# If $Ax=0$, then $A$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in M_{n \times n}$ and suppose there exists a nonzero vector $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$ such that $Ax = 0$. Show that matrix $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: What do you know about the eigenvalues of a matrix and the relationship between the eigenvalues and the determinant of a matrix?

Comment: There seems to be something missing from the problem statement. There always exists $X$ such that $AX=0,$ even if $A$ is invertible. But if $A$ is invertible and $AX=0$ you can find what $X$ must be. That may be a hint to the correct problem statement and its solution.

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant nonzero $X$, because if not the problem is clearly false.

Assume for contradiction that $A$ is invertible. Multiply $A^{-1}$ on the left on both sides to obtain $A^{-1} A X =0$. But this simply becomes $X=0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I’ve edited my answer. The problem statement probably meant nonzero $X$.

Answer (score -1):

$Ax$ as given produces a linear combination of the columns of $A$. If, for a non-zero $x$, this vanishes then the columns of $A$ must be linearly dependent. Its determinant is 0. $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math!